# Is there a way to monitor registry changes?

Tags: winapi, registry

could you tell me how to monitor registry changes (specified values) using WinAPI or so?

I know there is the function [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892.aspx) that allows to notify the caller about changes to the attributes or contents of a specified registry **key**, for example: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

But I need to see if value of *the specified* **parameter** in the key was changed:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Skype

So RegNotifyChangeKeyValue only works with keys and monitors *all* parameters of the specified key...

Thank you!

Comment: It is not a "parameter", it is a *value*.  Be sure to distinguish keys and values when working with the registry.  Pretty easy to see when you use Regedit.exe, keys are on the left and values are on the right.  Generating a notification when a value changes is what RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() was meant to do.

Comment: Hmmm... That's strange to see "value". In my country we have the following "model" of titles: [registry](http://content.screencast.com/users/The_Immortal/folders/Snagit/media/ec2ae6a2-cc4b-4f39-ab94-378b6c6a5606/12.10.2015-14.51.png). What's the correct title of "value" on my picture? "Data of value"? :)

Comment: See [What is the terminology for describing the various parts of the registry?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090204-00/?p=19263)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` is what you need. Pass in `REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET` as the notify filter argument, and whenever you receive notification you know that some value of the key has be added, deleted or modified. You must then check whether or not the specific value of interest has changed. There is no more fine-grained monitoring functionality available to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! But it seems there is another way - use WMI - RegistryValueChangeEvent. I'm going to try it.

Comment: `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` does not report which value was changed, but a kernel-mode driver can. This is how [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) reports detailed info about key/value accesses.